# SQL select * from * where txt/csv list

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a csv with a list containing certain ids that are useful to me. I wanted to make query from a table (lets call it friends) to get all the id's that are "friends"  to the ids contained in the csv. I know that you can query

```
SELECT id,friend_id 
FROM friends 
WHERE id IN ('id1', 'id2', etc)
```

but the list is 300 ids and I don't want to type them all manually. is there a way to search trough a file after `IN( )`?

Comment: Import the .CSV into a (TEMP)  table, and join with that table (or: use EXISTS() or IN() on that table.)

Answer (score 1):

If my database permitted at least 300 items (and I think [postgresql does](https://blog.dbi-services.com/what-is-the-maximum-in-list-size-in-postgresql/)) in an "IN" list, then I would use a text editor to reformat the list with single quotes and commas, and then copy and paste. Many text editors allow you to search for patterns/regular expressions, so you can do things like insert text at the beginning or end of a line, to turn it from a plain list of numbers into valid SQL. One can also format a list into a sequence of single row "insert" SQL statements.

This is not a completely general solution, and may have pitfalls if you are dealing with data more complex than simple integer IDs.